# WordPress - Showing the last post from all categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I just want to show the last post from all categories on my page. For I could do this, I've made the following code:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'ASC'
      );

    $categories = get_categories($args);

    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $categoryId = $category->cat_ID;

        query_posts('posts_per_page=1&cat=$categoryId');
        if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <span><?php echo $categoryId; ?></span>
        <?php
            endwhile;
        endif;
    }
        wp_reset_query();
?>
```

But the posts displayed are all the same. What I've forgot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i get only 1 post from each category in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264323/how-do-i-get-only-1-post-from-each-category-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
'posts_per_page=1&cat=$categoryId'
```

There's a significant difference between single and double quotes. Single quotes are for string literals. Variable interpolation requires double quotes.

Change it to either:

```
'posts_per_page=1&cat='.$categoryId
```

Or:

```
"posts_per_page=1&cat={$categoryId}"
```

Comment: Happens to the best of us, brotato. If this answered your question, make sure to accept it once you're able.

Answer (score -1):

Please use argument like this:

```
    $args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' =>'-1'
  );
```

posts_per_page = -1 used to fetch all posts.

Comment: Not only does this not answer the question, this does the exact opposite of what OP is asking for.